# How to read uploaded text file and replace string in the file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, replace

replace the string "$E Between $F" with BOLD Between

```js
 import React, { useState } from "react";
>     
>     export function Upload({ children }) {   const [files, setFiles] = useState("");
>     
>       const handleChange = e => {
>         const fileReader = new FileReader();
>         fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
>         fileReader.onload = e => {
>           console.log("e.target.result", e.target.result);
>           setFiles(e.target.result);
>         };   };   return (
>         <>
>           <h1>Upload Json file - Example</h1>
>     
>           <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
>           <br />
>           {"uploaded file content -- " + files}
>         </>   ); }
```

> import React, { useState } from "react";
>
> export function Upload({ children }) {   const [files, setFiles] =
> useState("");
>
> const handleChange = e => {
> const fileReader = new FileReader();
> fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
> fileReader.onload = e => {
> console.log("e.target.result", e.target.result);
> setFiles(e.target.result);
> };   };   return (
> <>
>
> ## Upload Json file - Example
>
> ```
>   <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
>   <br />
>   {"uploaded file content -- " + files}
> </>   ); }
> ```

Comment: Here is the content in text file "EMR R CHANDRAHASA RAO AND OTHERS            ... Judgement Debtors        F "   replace the string with bold <b>E-starting  </b>Fending of the line

Answer (score 0):

```
new FileReader().readAsText(file,“utf-8”);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: in above code file is reading but here i want to make changes in uploaded text file                             what to replace the string $E with <b> tag